# Passing Array to Vertex Shader as Attribute

Tags: opengl, glsl, vertex-shader, skinning

I am doing some LBS, and I need to use more than 4 weights, and indices (Let's say I need 60 `float` values, and 60 `int` values).

I am using `GLSL version 1.30`, so I cannot use `Shader Storage Buffer Object`. Since this weight, and index information will be different for each vertex, cannot use `uniform`, and I guess there is no way to define an array with a fixed size (for example `float arr[16]`) if you are not using `uniform`. Additionally, for `attribute` inputs, I can only use `vec/mat` `2`,`3` or `4`.

So, do you have any idea how I can solve this problem?

Comment: So you need 120 different values for each vertex?

Comment: Yes, in the worst case scenario

Comment: How can you need 120 values for each one, a vertex? I mean, why?

Comment: It looks you need 1 weight for 1 vertex but you need at least 15 vertices(vec4) which are float vert[60] with float weight[60] and int indices[60] right?

Answer (score 2):

A first approach would be to just pass them as normal vertex attributes. There is though a driver specific maximum number of vertex attributes.

---

A better approach, that should work with every driver and with an arbitrary amount of attributes (not infinite, but pretty many) is, to store the vertex attributes in a texture.

A simple setup would be to create a NxM texture, where N=#vertex_attributes and M=#vertices. Each vertex has then only one attribute, that indicates a line of the texture. In the vertex shader you can then read one line of the  texture per vertex and have all your attributes.

Comment: Thank you, it is a good idea. But, could you give me a little more idea about how I can generate a texture, and iterate it in the shader?

Comment: Creating a texture can be done with the following comands: `glGenTextures(...), glTexImage2D(...)` You should find plenty of tutorial how to use them. Accessing a texture in shader can be done with `texelFetch(...), texture(...)` again, just look at basic texture tutorials.